# PHP Twitter API Error

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have succesfully implemented Twitter Connect with PHP, got the key and secret. Now, I would like to get the user information, tweets from twitter. I am having the following problem :
 `Undefined variable: args`
on following line in EpiTwitter.php

```
return new EpiTwitterJson(call_user_func(array($this, 'httpRequest'), $method, $url, $args));
```

The error is appearing on following line:

```
$this->twitter_obj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of your code look like, have you defined $args above the return statement you pasted? You need to make sure the variables you pass in to that statement are assigned values before you make that call.